# Create copy of file on Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

How do I create a copy of an existing file in an Azure Blob Storage container using code? I'm using the `WindowsAzure.Storage` NuGet package to handle all operations related to my Azure Blob Storage.

To be 100% clear, I'm trying to create a complete and separate copy of a file that's already been uploaded to a container on Azure Blob Storage. I also want to give the file a new name in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purely in code, you'll want to use `StartCopyAsync()` a method on `CloudBlockBlob`, to start the copy process.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to use a logic app that triggers on a blob being created that will then copy the blob.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage

If you want to get more sophisticated, you can do a function app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function

Comment: yeah easiest way indeed :-)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think this is a really good way if I don't want my app involved in the copy process. If I use `StartCopyAsync()`, I think I'm essentially creating a file stream in to my app, then creating a copy streaming out the bits out of my app. Am I getting it right?

Comment: @Sam - no, there is no bits streaming to and from your app. The copy is done within Azure Storage itself, which is initiated via the call to `StartCopyAsync()`.